# Clip mouse movement in Carbon

Tags: macos, mouse, macos-carbon, clip

How can I clip the mouse movement into a window Region using Carbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any simple way to do it, and that's good... it's a "non-Mac-like" behavior that will freak out your users.  That said, it would probably be possible to use `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition` to uncouple the mouse from the cursor position, then monitor mouse events and move the cursor to where you want.